# Help with elementary set theory proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Consider the following three sets:

$$A = \{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid (x-3)(x-5)>0\}$$

$$B = \{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid x<3\}$$

$$C = \{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid x>5\}$$

Prove that $B \cup C \subseteq A$.

I said that $B\cup C \subseteq A$ because $B \cup C = \emptyset$ and $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set but was marked wrong and I'm not sure how else to go about this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It seems you were thinking of the intersection $B \cap C$ instead of the union $B \cup C$. The intersection $B \cap C=\emptyset$ but $B \cup C = (-\infty, 3) \cup (5, \infty)$

Comment: With set containment, always pick an element from the first set, and show it is also in the second set. This is very straightforward.

Comment: Union means any element from any set in the collection. So $B \cup C = (-\infty,3) \cup (5, \infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

Just look at the two cases:

$$(x-5)(x-3)>0$$

i) $(x-5)>0$ and $(x-3)>0$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $x>5$

ii) $(x-5)<0$ and $(x-3)<0$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $x<3$

Since the solution set in i) is $C$, $B$ in ii) and the inequality we look at describes $A$, it ultimately follows that
$B\cup C \subseteq A$.